# A word for knowing the truth but not wanting to believe it

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

What is the word for someone who knows someone else is lying but accepts it

Comment: It seems like your question title and question body are describing two different things.

Comment: [**Denial**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial) - leading to usages such as [Holocaust denier](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2009/02/adolf_who.html)

Comment: Going by the question in the body, willful ignorance or willful denial if it is willful and cognitive dissonance as a logical fallacy.

Comment: This seems very broad.  What does “accept” mean?  Perhaps the listener (“L”) thinks that it is not worth the bother to correct the speaker (“S”).  Perhaps L wants to deceive S; to make S believe that L believes what S said.  (L wants S to believe that L trusts S.)  Or a vanity-type issue (“You’re very handsome.”) that L wishes were true.  Or do you mean that L *takes action based on the statement* (e.g., “The speed limit here is 70 mph.”) — perhaps to create “plausible deniability” (“But officer, S told me …”)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it would apply where you intend to use it but 'cognitive dissonance' would apply where someone believes two contrary opinions.

For example when a person knows their spouse is cheating on them but also refuses to believe their spouse is cheating that person is experiencing cognitive dissonance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance

Answer (score 0):

Such a person is **compliant** or **complaisant**

> *complaisant* adjective
>
> Willing to please others or to accept what they do or say without
>   protest
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/complaisant)

Answer (score -1):

Cuckold. Delusional. Blinkered. Naïve. Accepting. Credulous. Dupable. Overtrusting. Trustful. Spineless.

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion.